# TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable when trying to create 2 subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create two subplots in the same output. But I get a `Type Error: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable` when trying to create ax.1 and ax.2

Below is an example of the code and what I've tried to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plot 1 data
x1_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))
y1_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))

#plot 2 data
x2_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))
y2_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))

#scatter plot 1
scatter1 = ax1.scatter(x1_data[0], y1_data[0]) 

#scatter plot 2
scatter2 = ax2.scatter(x2_data[0], y2_data[0]) 

plt.draw()
```

I tried `.add_subplot()` but get the same error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to specify either

```
>>> plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8,6))
```

or

```
>>> plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8,6))
```

Otherwise, only one `Axes` is returned, and you are trying to do iterable unpacking on it, which won't work.

The [call signature](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) is `subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, ...)`.

```
>>> fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 6))
>>> scatter1 = ax1.scatter(x1_data[0], y1_data[0]) 
>>> scatter2 = ax2.scatter(x2_data[0], y2_data[0])
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `.add_subplot()`.  First create a Figure, then add to it:

```
>>> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
>>> ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
>>> ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
>>> ax1.scatter(x1_data[0], y1_data[0]) 
>>> ax2.scatter(x2_data[0], y2_data[0])
```

[image]

Comment: After making this fix, if your code continues to show the same error, try adding  `squeeze=False` as an argument to `plt.subplots()`